# Retornar jSON para uma variavel

Tags: php, jquery, json

Tenho um código em PHP que cria um jSON:

```
<?php

$array3 = array(array('0,1300', 'Thalita', 'Nicole'));


echo json_encode($array3);
?>
```

E tenho um outro código que é em jQuery que forma um gráfico, com as seguintes configurações:

```
var d1 = [
        [0, 1450], [1, 1300], [2, 1600], [3, 1900], [4, 2100], [5, 2500], [6, 2200], [7, 2000], [8, 1950], [9, 1900], [10, 2000], [11, 2120]
    ];
```

Eu preciso fazer é pegar o retorno do jSON que criei com o PHP e jogar nessa váriavel **d1** para formar o gráfico de forma correta. E não esquecendo que tem que retornar com duas **[[ ]]** como a variavel **d1** acima.

Comment: Como você está querendo processar o retorno PHP? Seria por meio de um método?

Comment: Eu gostaria de pegar o retorno do PHP, pode ser por $.post, $.ajax e jogar o resultado e jogar na variavel jQuery. Preciso formar uma variavel igual a d1.

Comment: @AlissonAcioli, as duas arrays são diferentes. Uma tem dois campos por array, a outra 3 e não numéricos. Que gráfico está a usar? Flot? HighCharts?

Comment: Apenas lembrando que nas últimas versões do PHP você pode declarar arrays de uma forma bem parecida com o do JavaScript. O primeiro array com nomes que você criou seria:

$array3 = [['0,1300', 'Thalita', 'Nicole']];

Já pra criar o array que você deseja:

$array = [[0 => 1450, 1=>1300, 2=>1600, 3=>1900]]; // etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se for assim, você pode criar esse array no PHP como você está criando, e mandar ele por meio de uma função:

```
<?PHP
    $array3 = array(array('0,1300', 'Thalita', 'Nicole'));
    $jsonArr=json_encode($array3);
?>
<script>
    function makeGraph(data){
        d1=data;
        //manipulação de array dentro do javascript...
    }
</script>
<body onload="javascript:makeGraph(<?= $jsonArr ?>);">
```

A ação `onload` no body foi só pra demonstrar a chamada do método, você pode colocar o código de dentro dela em qualquer script ou ação do HTML.

Comment: Mas o PHP está em uma página e o JS em outra. E a variavel d1  terá q ficar fora da function, se não, não joga pra variavel do gráfico

Comment: Dá pra colocar um pouco mais do seu código do jQuery e do PHP na sua pergunta? Tá um pouco difícil de entender o que o código deve fazer.

Comment: Eu achei um código na internet aqui que até faz o que eu quero, só que na hora de executar a página para de funcionar, da um erro no chrome, ai eu clico em Recarregar e acontece mesma coisa. Mas o que eu quero é o seguinte, criar um gráfico com jQuery + PHP, para pegar os dados do gráfico dinamicamente com PHP. Você ou alguém teria um para indicar?

Comment: Tem o Highcharts, você pode passar os dados por AJAX ou até mesmo pelo próprio PHP, colocando código PHP na tag script. Também tem o PHPChart e o jPChart.
Links: https://www.google.com.br/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=PHP+charts&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=F-PCU4inDqOX8Qejp4H4Cg e http://www.highcharts.com/